# If Tcpclient can't connect

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# and now i trying learn `TcpClient`, `TcpListener` and `NetworkStream`.
On Youtube and other C# tutorials i can find basic Tcp connection between Client and server. I tried make something like

```
if (Client.connect(ServerIP, ServerPORT))
{
     MessagaToTxtbox("Connected");
}
else
{
     MessageToTxtbox("Can't connect. Reason can be :\r\n1.Server is down.\r\n2.You lost internet connection");
}
```

I thought this gonna work based on my php knowledge, but seems i was wrong! :D

So my question is:
How to check if `tcpclient.connect(ServerIP, ServerPORT)` is success. As i know `TcpClient.Connected` is the way to check if connection is still on, i want to check if client is made connection, if not, i can drop message or do some other functions. :)

Comment: What about reading at least the definition of the function on the documentation where it's described how it works? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbhht5w(v=vs.110).aspx (in other words, RTFM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exception handling mechanism and wrap it in a `try .. catch` block like below. So if at all connection establishing fails due to some reason, you catch it and show proper message to UI and log it if needed

```
try
{
  Client.connect(ServerIP, ServerPORT));
  MessagaToTxtbox("Connected");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageToTxtbox("Can't connect. Reason can be :\r\n1.Server is down.\r\n2.You lost internet connection");
}
```

Comment: Shame on me! Why i didn't think about it! :) Thank you. :) +1

Comment: @AleksZiemelis, consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button